# Use a function in Powershell replace

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to replace part of a string in Powershell. However, the replacement string is not hardcoded, it's calculated from a function:

```
$text = "the image is -12345-"
$text = $text -replace "-(\d*)-", 'This is the image: $1'
Write-Host $text
```

This gives me the correct result:
    "This is the image: 12345"

Now, I want to include the base64 encoded image. I can read the image from the id. I was hoping the following would work, but it doesn't:

```
function Get-Base64($path)
{
    [convert]::ToBase64String((get-content $path -encoding byte))
}
$text -replace "-(\d*)-", "This is the image: $(Get-Base64 '$1')"
```

The reason that it doesn't work, is because it first passes `$1` (the string, not the value of `$1`) to the function, executes it and only then does it do the replace. What I want to do is

- Find the occurrence of the pattern
- Replace each occurence with the pattern
- For each replace:
- Pass the capture group to the function
- Use the value of the capture group to get the base64 image
- inject the base64 image into the replacement

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use the static [`Replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ht1sxswy.aspx) method from the `[regex]` class:

```
[regex]::Replace($text,'-(\d*)-',{param($match) "This is the image: $(Get-Base64 $match.Groups[1].Value)"})
```

Alternatively you can define a `regex` object and use the `Replace` method of that object:

```
$re = [regex]'-(\d*)-'
$re.Replace($text, {param($match) "This is the image: $(Get-Base64 $match.Groups[1].Value)"})
```

For better readability you could define the callback function (the scriptblock) in a separate variable and use that in the replacement:

```
$callback = {
  param($match)
  'This is the image: ' + (Get-Base64 $match.Groups[1].Value)
}

$re = [regex]'-(\d*)-'
$re.Replace($text, $callback)
```

Comment: For those looking to understand the derivation of this, it is using a sigature of the `Replace` method ( [Regex.Replace Method (String, MatchEvaluator)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ) that adds even more power to regexs by allowing computation on a matched argument. The neat thing is--which I did not realize until I saw this answer--is that a PowerShell script block is apparently compatible with a MatchEvaluator argument!

Answer (score 15):

Note: As for *why* your own, string-based attempt didn't work: see the explanation in the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77349487/45375).

---

[PetSerAl's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30666293/45375) is your only option in **Windows PowerShell**.

**[*PowerShell (Core)*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)**, since v6.1, now **offers a *native PowerShell solution* via an enhancement to the `-replace` operator**, which obviates the need to call [`[regex]::Replace()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace):

Just as with `[regex]::Replace()`, you can now:

- **pass a *script block* as the `-replace` replacement operand**, which must return the replacement string,
- however, unlike with `[regex]::Replace()`, the **match at hand** (an instance of type [`[System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match)) is reflected in the [automatic **`$_`** variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_), as is customary in PowerShell.

Applied to your case:

```bash
# PowerShell v6.1+ only
$text -replace "-(\d*)-", { "This is the image: $(Get-Base64 $_.Groups[1].Value)" }
```

A simpler example:

```bash
# PowerShell v6.1+ only
# Increment the number embedded in a string:
# -> '43 years old'
'42 years old' -replace '\d+', { [int] $_.Value + 1 }
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Comment: `PS> '42 years old' -replace '\d+', { [int] $_.Value + 1 }` returns `[int] 42 years old.Value + 1  years old`

Comment: @Ωmega, that's what happens in _Windows PowerShell_, where using script blocks as substitution operand isn't supported (the script  block is simply _stringified_ there, meaning that its _verbatim contents_ (sans `{` and `}`) are used. As the answer notes, you need [_PowerShell (Core)_](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), version 6.1 or above (current is v7.3.8).

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way.  Use the -match operator, and then reference $matches.  Note that $matches doesn't get set with arrays on the left side of the -match operator.  $matches.1 is the first grouping formed by the ( ).

```
$text = "the image is -12345-"
function Get-Base64($path) { 
  [convert]::ToBase64String( (get-content $path -asbytestream) ) }  # ps 6 ver
if (! (test-path 12345)) { echo hi > 12345 }
$text -match '-(\d*)-'
$text -replace '-(\d*)-', "$(Get-Base64 $matches.1)"

the image is aGkNCg==
```

Or to break it up even more:

```
$text -match '-(\d*)-'
$result = Get-Base64 $matches.1
$text -replace '-(\d*)-', $result
```