# How can I change the case of a substitution variable in a -replace using powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to change the case of a thing in a file (thousands of files, in fact) using something like this...

```
ls *.pro | ForEach-Object {
    (Get-Content -Path $_.FullName) -replace "sender_name\(\s*``([^``]+)``\s*\)", 'sender_name( `$1` )'
}
```

I have no idea how to get the substitution variable, $1 to be lower case (or better yet, proper case)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use a function in Powershell replace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30666101/use-a-function-in-powershell-replace)

Answer (score 0):

The `-replace` operator doesn't support fancy postprocessing of the substitution string. You'll have to use [`Regex.Replace()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c(v=vs.110).aspx) on each line instead:

```
# Define your regex matcher
$Regex = [regex]'sender_name\(\s*`([^`]+)`\s*\)'

Get-ChildItem *.pro |ForEach-Object {
    Get-Content $_.FullName |ForEach-Object {
        # Replace using a match evaluator
        $Regex.Replace($_,{param($MatchInfo) $MatchInfo.Groups[1].Value.ToLower()})
    }
}
```