# Replace multiple dots in string with different character but same amount

Tags: regex, string, powershell, replace

I have a string like the following
"blaa...blup..blaaa...bla."

Every part where there is more than one dot must be replaced by "_" but it must have the same amount as replaced chars.

The string should result in:
"bla___blup__blaaa___bla."

Notice that the last dot is not replaced as it has not other dots "connected".

I tried using following regex approach in powershell but I always get a legnth of 2 for the match regardless if there where 3 or more dots:

```
$string -replace '(.)\1+',("_"*'$&'.length)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use a function in Powershell replace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30666101/use-a-function-in-powershell-replace)

Comment: @PetSerAl: Why? It can be easily solved with a single regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Given the OP code, I think it what he trying to do, so I vote for it.

Comment: Yeah, true. I will add a note about that in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, I could solve my problem with this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [\G anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html) to glue a match to the previous.

```
\.(?=\.)|\G(?!^)\.
```

- `\.(?=\.)` match a period if another one is [ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).
- `|\G(?!^)\.` or replace period if there was a previous match (but not start)

Replace with underscore. [See demo at regexstorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c.(%3f%3d%5c.)%7c%5cG(%3f!%5e)%5c.&i=blaa...blup..blaaa...bla.&r=_)

Comment: :) Good choice of the alternatives :) Yours seems the best suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following pattern:

```
\.(?=\.)|(?<=\.)\.
```

And replace with `_`.

The pattern simply looks for either a period that is preceded by a period or a period which is followed by a period:

- `\.(?=\.)` - Matches a period which is followed by a period
- `|` - Or
- `(?<=\.)\.` - Matches a period which is preceded by a period

See the [online demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5C.(%3F%3D%5C.)%7C(%3F%3C%3D%5C.)%5C.&i=blaa...blup..blaaa...bla.&r=_).

Answer (score 3):

None of the languages and regex flavors I know allow you to evaluate the backreference numeric value "on the fly", you can only use it in the callback function. See [*Use a function in Powershell replace*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30666101/use-a-function-in-powershell-replace).

However, in this particular case, you can use the following regex:

```
((?=\.{2})|(?!^)\G)\.
```

And replace with `_`.

See the [regex demo here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=((%3F%3D%5C.%7B2%7D)%7C(%3F!%5E)%5CG)%5C.&i=blaa...blup..blaaa...bla.&r=_).

[image]

And the explanation:

- `((?=\.{2})|(?!^)\G)` - a boundary that either matches a location before 2 dots (with `(?=\.{2})`) or the end of the previous successful match (with `(?!^)\G`)
- `\.` - a literal dot.

Comment: @Shihan: bobble bubble's suggestion is the most efficient although all regexps here are working as you expect.