# Match the strings with keys and replace the values using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a loop for matching the strings with keys in the dictionary.

I'm trying to match each and every string in the app.config file with each and every key in the dictionary. for example, there is one string called "client", I have to match this string with all the keys in dictionary. 
if the string matches, replace the value "Arizona" with string in app.config file, otherwise skip.

Can someone please suggest me in writing the loop for matching and replacing.

Comment: Use [`[Regex]::Replace` with `MatchEvaluator`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30666293).

Comment: @PetSerAl
Actually I'm trying to write separate script just for matching the strings and replacing the values.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question, then don't see any reason to use Regex.Replace here.  String.Replace is probably better since you want to match literal string values.

The weird thing about hash tables is that they're harder to enumerate than arrays, so they're a bit more awkward to feed to foreach or ForEach-Object.

Try something like this:

```
foreach ($Key in $HashTable.Keys) {
    $FieldName = '{{' + $Key.ToString() + '}}';
    $FieldValue = $HashTable.Item($Key).ToString();
    $AppConfig = $AppConfig.Replace($FieldName, $FieldValue);
}
```

Or you can use this:

```
foreach ($Hash in $HashTable.GetEnumerator()) {
    $FieldName = '{{' + $Hash.Key.ToString() + '}}';
    $FieldValue = $Hash.Value.ToString();
    $AppConfig = $AppConfig.Replace($FieldName, $FieldValue);
}
```

Both should work.  You must specify the `GetEnumerator()` method because hash tables are not normally enumerated objects.

Comment: Why use regex? Because it's usually faster, doesn't require a loop and it's fun. :-)

Comment: @Bacon Bits, Thanks for sharing the solution. But somehow it is not able to replace the values.

Answer (score 0):

The simple implementation for the script will look like below. I have tested it for the inputs you have specified successfully.

```
[regex]::Replace($appConfigFile, "{{(\w*)}}",{param($match) $dictionaryObject[$($match.Groups[1].Value)]})
```

**Assuming**,
$appConfigFile has the contents of the App.Config file and $dictionaryObject has been created as below:

```
$dictionaryObject = @{}
$dictionaryObject.Add("client","Arizona") 
$dictionaryObject.Add("type","Test")
```

...and so on.

**Reference:** [Regex.Replace Method (String, MatchEvaluator)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)