# Replacing dynamic variables using REGEX content as variable in Azure CD Pipeline Powershell Task

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, continuous-deployment

I'm writing custom Powershell Azure CD Pipeline task(for VM) where my web.config should be replaced with pipeline variables. I have sample config file as with **WebService** and **AuditService** defined in my Azure CD pipeline variables.

```
<client>
      <endpoint address="__WebService__" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ServiceSoap" contract="WebServiceClient.ServiceSoap" name="NLSService" />
      <endpoint address="__AuditService__" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_Audit" contract="AuditApiService.Audit" name="AuditService" />
    </client>
```

I have powershell script as

```
$zipfileName = "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\_WebService-CI\drop\Service.zip"
$fileToEdit = "web.config"
$reg = [regex] '__(.*?)__'


[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.IO.Compression.FileSystem");
# Open zip and find the particular file (assumes only one inside the Zip file)
$zip =  [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::Open($zipfileName,"Update")
$configFile = $zip.Entries.Where({$_.name -like $fileToEdit})

# Read the contents of the file
$desiredFile = [System.IO.StreamReader]($configFile).Open()
$text = $desiredFile.ReadToEnd()
$desiredFile.Close()
$desiredFile.Dispose()


$text = $text -replace $reg, $(${1}) -join "`r`n"
    #update file with new content
$desiredFile = [System.IO.StreamWriter]($configFile).Open()
$desiredFile.BaseStream.SetLength(0)

# Insert the $text to the file and close
$desiredFile.Write($text)
$desiredFile.Flush()
$desiredFile.Close()

# Write the changes and close the zip file
$zip.Dispose()
```

So how do I can replace dynamically Regex content within "__" and treat that content as a variable which should look into pipeline variables and replace it in line :

`$text = $text -replace $reg, $(${1}) -join "`r`n"`

Comment: Heed the other answer. It very likely is a better approach. If you choose to stay on this one look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30666101/use-a-function-in-powershell-replace which you can incorporate with a hashtable of replacements that would work here just fine.

Comment: Can't you use the [Transform web.config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/transform-webconfig?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't use `Replace Tokens` or [Transform Web.config file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/transform-webconfig?view=aspnetcore-3.1), here is something :

According to the fact that `web.config` file contains :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For ...
  -->
<configuration>
..
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="checkVatBinding" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="__WebService__" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ServiceSoap" contract="WebServiceClient.ServiceSoap" name="NLSService" />
      <endpoint address="__AuditService__" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_Audit" contract="AuditApiService.Audit" name="AuditService" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

You  can try the following :

```
# Get all the file in a single var in spite of an array    
$data = Get-Content "D:\temp\web.config" -raw
$reg = [Regex]::new( '__(.*?)__', [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::Singleline)
# Here are the vars with the final values
$WebService = "http://Aurillac.fr"
$AuditService = "http://Cantal.fr"
# Here is how to replace
$reg.replace($data, {param ($p);return (Get-Variable -Name $p.groups[1]).Value})
```

Explanations :

- The `-raw` in `Get-Content` allows to get all the characters in a single string
- I use the `.NET RegEx` class with the option `Singleline` to allow search accross cariage return line feed (perhaps not necessary)
- I use the `Regex Replace` method with a `MatchEvaluator Delegate` method translated in PowerShell by a `Scriptblock` to get the variable with the name catched by the RegEx.

It gives :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For ...
  -->
<configuration>
..
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="checkVatBinding" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://Aurillac.fr" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ServiceSoap" contract="WebServiceClient.ServiceSoap" name="NLSService" />
      <endpoint address="http://Cantal.fr" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_Audit" contract="AuditApiService.Audit" name="AuditService" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you can't use the Replace Tokens task from the marketplace?  This is my go-to for replacing values in config files.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens

Comment: Replace tokens step(Target files is the SetParameters.xml path) does says, it replaced the tokens but when I deploy with WinRM IIS web app deployment as a next step on Virtual machine, I don't see them transformed.