# Convert DateTime within regex replace

Tags: regex, powershell

**I am using PS ver 5.1.23560.1000**

---

Let's have a simple `input.txt` file like this:

```
@{Name=file1.txt; LastAccessTime=10/22/2023 6:59:16 PM}
@{Name=file2.txt; LastAccessTime=10/22/2023 6:59:22 PM}
```

---

I want to display date-time followed by the filename, but I want to convert date-time into `yyyyMMddHHmmss` format.

So I am going to use this type of date-time conversion (example):

```
PS> ([datetime]'10/22/2023 6:59:16 PM').ToString('yyyyMMddHHmmss')
20231022185916
```

Great!

---

To get a desired output, I used:

```
Get-Content 'input.txt' | % { $_ -replace '^.*=(.*); Last\w+Time=(.*)}.*$', ($(([datetime]'$2').ToString('yyyyMMddHHmmss')) + "`t" + '$1') }
```

Unfortunately, instead of

```
20231022185916   file1.txt
20231022185922   file2.txt
```

I got this:

```
Cannot convert value "$2" to type "System.DateTime". Error: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
At line:1 char:102
+ ... ime=(.*)}.*$', ($(([datetime]'$2').ToString('yyyyMMddHHmmss')) + "`t" ...
+                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastParseTargetInvocationWithFormatProvider

        file1.txt
Cannot convert value "$2" to type "System.DateTime". Error: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
At line:1 char:102
+ ... ime=(.*)}.*$', ($(([datetime]'$2').ToString('yyyyMMddHHmmss')) + "`t" ...
+                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastParseTargetInvocationWithFormatProvider

        file2.txt
```

**What am I doing wrong? What should be the correct syntax?**

Please note I have to use `-replace`, as my problem is more complex than this simple presentation.

Comment: How do you end up with stringified objects in a text file?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon – it is an output from a different program, not related to my PS code

Comment: You cannot pass the text backreference to the function, of course `$2` *text* is not a valid DateTime, see [how it is done in Powershell properly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52012557/3832970).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew – the other post works with PowerShell v6.1+ only  :(

Comment: If you'd like a bit more flexibility, I'd recommend converting them into objects:`% { $hashtable = Invoke-Expression -Command ($_ -replace '(?<==)(.+?)(?=;|})','"$1"'); '{0} {1}' -f ([datetime]$hashtable['LastAccessTime']).ToString('yyyyMMddHHmmss'), $hashtable['Name'] }`

Comment: you're asking for something that is not implemented in the powershell version you're using. if you don't like then upgrade your powershell version or use the .NET API that allows you to do such thing as mklement0 has pointed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without completely ignoring the tons of articles on [Avoiding the use of `Invoke-Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/avoid-using-invoke-expression?view=powershell-5.1), it offers a quick solution to your immediate problem when considering the comments.

Since hashtables won't take values of certain *values* *as*-*is*, you'd have to quote them so they all get listed as type `[string]`. With that said, you can make use of the following pattern to get the grouping quoted which would be your values:

```
(?<==)(.+?)(?=;|})','"$1"'
```

This just allows for further *type conversion* down the line if needed.

```
$hashtable = Invoke-Expression -Command ($_ -replace '(?<==)(.+?)(?=;|})','"$1"')
'{0} {1}' -f ([datetime]$hashtable['LastAccessTime']).ToString('yyyyMMddHHmmss'), $hashtable['Name']
```

If there are any concerns on the use of `Invoke-Expression`, you can always use a different approach such as `ConvertFrom-StringData` as well:

```
$hashtables = 
    Get-Content 'input.txt' | 
    % { 
        ($_ -replace "@{|}", "") -replace ";", "`n" | ConvertFrom-StringData 
    }

'{0} {1}' -f ([datetime]$hashtables[0]['LastAccessTime']).ToString('yyyyMMddHHmmss'), $hashtables[0]['Name']
```

Answer (score 1):

To offer an alternative to [Abraham Zinala's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77348286/45375) that doesn't require `Invoke-Expression`:

```bash
$file, $date = [regex]::Matches($_, '(?<==)(.+?)(?=[;}])').Value
"{0}`t{1}" -f ([datetime] $date).ToString('yyyyMMddHHmmss'), $file
```

[`[regex]::Matches()]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches) is used to extract all matches for the *values* in your hashtable-*like* string representation, which are then reformatted and output.

Note:

- As of PowerShell 7.3.x, use of PowerShell's [`-match` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch) is *not* an option, because it only ever finds at most *one* match. [GitHub issue #7867](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7867) proposes introducing a `-matchall` operator to remedy that; while the proposal has been green-lit, no one has stepped up to implement it yet.

---

As for your **desire to use a single [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operation**:

As demonstrated in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30666101/45375), your attempt **to *run code for each match* requires** the ability to **pass a [*script block*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`)** as the substitution operand (see below for why), which is **only supported in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)**:

```bash
# PowerShell 7+ only.
# $_ is a [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match] instance 
# representing the match at hand.
# Note the need to refer to capture groups via $_.Groups,
# which contains nested [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match] instances.
$_ -replace '^.*=(.*); Last\w+Time=(.*)}.*$', { 
    "{0}`t{1}" -f ([datetime] $_.Groups[2].Value).ToString('yyyyMMddHHmmss'), 
                  $_.Groups[1].Value
  }
```

<sup>Note the use of the [`-f`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#format-operator--f) operator to format the output string.</sup>

As also shown in the linked post, in ***Windows PowerShell*** - where `-replace` lacks script-block support - you can **achieve the same effect by *directly calling the underlying [`[regex]::Replace()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace) .NET API*** with a script block:

```bash
# Also works in Windows PowerShell.
# What is passed to parameter $m is a [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match] 
# instance representing the match at hand.
[regex]::Replace(
  $_,
  '^.*=(.*); Last\w+Time=(.*)}.*$', 
  {
    param($m)
    "{0}`t{1}" -f ([datetime] $m.Groups[2].Value).ToString('yyyyMMddHHmmss'),
                  $m.Groups[1].Value
  }
)
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

> `` $_ -replace '...', ($(([datetime]'$2').ToString('yyyyMMddHHmmss')) + "`t" + '$1') ``

**Unless you pass a *script block* as the substitution operand** (the second RHS operand) - which, as noted, only works in PowerShell (Core) 7+ - this **operand is invariably treated *as a string***.

Therefore, **whatever you pass is *evaluated up front*** (and possibly coerced to a string), before the `-replace` operator even sees its operands.

- Specifically, the code inside your [`(...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--) expression was evaluated *ahead of time* and therefore predictably failed, given that `$2` and `$1` were used *verbatim*, and `[datetime] '$2'` caused an error.

**With a *string* substitution operand it is therefore impossible to perform *dynamic operations* on *every reported match*.**

The ***only dynamic aspect* supported in string substitution operands is to use *placeholders interpreted by the .NET regex engine*** that allow you to **refer to parts of what the regex matched**, such as `$1` and `$2` to refer to what the first and second capture groups matched. [These placeholders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/substitutions-in-regular-expressions) only *happen to look like* PowerShell variables, but are entirely unrelated.

- In `"..."` strings, i.e. [*expandable* (interpolating) PowerShell strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings), the `$` chars. must be *escaped* in order to be passed through to the regex engine (e.g., `` "`$1" ``), and the same goes for the *regex* operand. This is why it's generally preferable to use `'...'`, i.e. [*verbatim* string literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings) in regex operations, and - if necessary - perform any required up-front string interpolation in a separate expression to clearly separate the verbatim and interpolated parts (e.g. `` 'foo' -replace 'o', ('@' + "`t") `` or `` 'foo' -replace 'o', ('@{0}' -f "`t") ``)

However, given that with a string substitution operand a *static string value* is passed to the .NET regex engine, **the only control you get over these placeholders and therefore their runtime values is *where to place them inside the string***.

---

To get the desired dynamic functionality, i.e., **to dynamically operate on each match found, a *callback mechanism* is required**:

- **At the level of the .NET APIs**, the caller can pass a piece of code to serve as the callback target in the form of a **[`System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchEvaluator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchEvaluator) *delegate*** to [`[regex]::Matches()]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches).

  - **PowerShell is flexible enough to allow you to pass a *script block* as that delegate**, which can access the delegate parameter representing the *match at hand* (a [`System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match)  instance) either via the [automatic `$args` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#args) or via a formally declared parameter inside the script block (see `param($m)` above).
  - In *Windows PowerShell* (the legacy, Windows-only edition whose latest *and last* version is v5.1), calling the .NET API directly is your *only* option.
- ***PowerShell (Core) 7+*** (the modern, cross-platform successor edition) now **surfaces the same functionality in a *PowerShell-idiomatic*  manner, via the `-replace` *operator***:

  - You can now pass a callback script block *directly to the [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operator* as its substitution operand.
  - However, in keeping with making the feature PowerShell-idiomatic, the script block receives the match at hand *implicitly*, via the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_)