# Adding left padding using regex in Powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a bunch of files, looking like this:

```
Prop.houses-2119-1
Prop.houses-2119-03
```

this should be renamed like this:

```
Prop<4-digits>house<2-digits>.house
Example:

Prop2119house01.house
Prop2119house03.house
```

So at the second block of numbers I have to add zeros if there is only one digit.

My code until now looks like this:

```
$propertyFiles = Get-ChildItem . *.property -rec
foreach ($file in $propertyFiles) {
(Get-Content $file) `
    -replace '(Prop.houses-)(\d+)(-)(\d+)', 'Prop$2house$4.house' `
    -replace 'second regex', 'second replacement' |
  Out-File $file
}
```

It is working fine, but I don't know how to add padLeft(2,'0') to the second block of numbers. It shows me the padLeft as a string.

Comment: The question is "*I don't know how to add padLeft(2,'0') to the second block of numbers*". The [**Use a function in Powershell replace**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30666101/3832970) explains how it is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The potential duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30666101/3832970) indeed shows the technique needed to implement your intent:

- **You want to perform a *dynamic operation* on a part of the matched string, based on *its specific value***, so as to be able to use a (conditionally) *transformed* version of it in the output string produced by a **[`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator)**-based string-substitution operation.
- This **can *not* be done with a *string* as the substitution operand**,<sup>[1]</sup> and instead **requires a *callback mechanism***; in the context of PowerShell, it **requires a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ .. }`)**, whose use with `-replace` is **only supported in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)**, however.

  - In ***Windows PowerShell***, you must **call the underlying .NET API,  [`[regex]::Replace()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace), directly**, as shown in the linked post.
  - The only substantial difference is in how the script block receives the match-information object (of type [`[Match]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match)) that represents the matched string:

    - In PS 7+, with `-replace`, it is reflected in the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_) (aka `$PSItem`).
    - With a direct `[regex]::Replace()` call, it is in the first positional *argument*, `$args[0]`, via the [automatic `$args` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#args) - though you're free to *declare a parameter* instead, as shown in the linked post (`param($match)`).

However, there's a **twist to your requirements** that to me warrants answering this question separately:

- The need to not just perform a *dynamic transformation*, but to do so in the context of *matching the input string as a whole* and *rearranging its - selectively transformed - substrings*.

The ***immediate* answer to your question** - which is focused on **an *additional* `-replace` operation, *after* having rearranged substrings** - is the following:

```bash
# PS 7+ only
# Make sure that a single digit before '.house' is 0-padded to 2 digits.
# * $_ is a [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match] instance with information
#   about the matched string.
# * $_.Value is the matched string itself, on which .PadLeft() can be called.
# -> 'Prop2119house01.house'
'Prop2119house1.house' -replace '(?<!\d)\d\b', { $_.Value.PadLeft(2, '0') }
```

Note:

- This is essentially the same technique as in the linked post, but with the simplification of using a *negative lookbehind assertion* (`(?<!...)`) and a *word-boundary assertion* to (`\b`) so as to avoid having to use capture groups (`(...)`) - see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/FEeMYm/1) for an explanation of the regex and the option to experiment with it.

However, you can use this technique to **make do with a *single* `-replace` operation, which *combines* rearranging substrings with selective dynamic transformations**, based on matching and replacing the *whole* input string, with the substring of interest captured via *capture groups* (`(...)`):

```bash
# PS 7+ only

# Sample input lines.
$lines = 'Prop.houses-2119-1', 'Prop.houses-2119-03'

# * $_.Groups[1].Value is the text captured by the 1st capture group, and so on.
# -> 'Prop2119house01.house', 'Prop2119house03.house'
$lines -replace 'Prop\.houses-(\d+)-(\d+)', { 
  'Prop{0}house{1}.house' -f $_.Groups[1].Value, $_.Groups[2].Value.PadLeft(2, '0') 
}
```

Note the use of `-f`, the [format operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#format-operator--f), to assemble the final string; in the template string, `{0}` is a placeholder for the first RHS operand, and so on.

---

<sup>[1] For a detailed explanation, see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77349487/45375)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You could use `-match` instead of `-replace` in this case, then using [`$Matches`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#matches) you can apply the zero left padding without issues:

```bash
$strings = @(
    'Prop.houses-2119-1'
    'Prop.houses-2119-03'
)

$strings | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_ -match '^(\D+)\.(\D+?)s?-(\d{4})-(\d{1,})$') {
        '{0}{1}{2}{3}.{2}' -f $Matches[1], $Matches[3], $Matches[2], $Matches[4].PadLeft(2, '0')
    }
}
```

In your code, applying this logic it would be:

```bash
foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem . *.property -rec) {
    (Get-Content $file) | ForEach-Object {
        # if the line matches the pattern
        if ($_ -match '^(\D+)\.(\D+?)s?-(\d{4})-(\d{1,})$') {
            # output the updated string
            '{0}{1}{2}{3}.{2}' -f $Matches[1], $Matches[3], $Matches[2], $Matches[4].PadLeft(2, '0')
            # and go next line
            return
        }

        # otherwise, output the line as is
        $_
    } | Out-File $file
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly...

```
$string = 'Prop.houses-2119-1'
$prop,$house,$year,$num = $string -split '\.|-'
$house = $house -replace 's$'
$num = [int]$num | % tostring 00
"$prop$year$house$num.$house"

Prop2119house01.house
```

Answer (score -2):

This can be achieved with basic string manipulation rather than a regex:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem "C:\Temp\.so" -File

foreach($f in $files)
{    
#splitting on the dashes isolates the numbers
    $splitOnDashes = $f.Name.split('-')

#splitting on the period isolates the Prop and Houses elements
    $propHouses = $splitOnDashes[0].Split('.')

#if the split element containing the one or two digit number is one number, pad a zero
    if($splitOnDashes[2].Length -eq 1)
    {
        $splitOnDashes[2] = "0$($splitOnDashes[2])"
    }
# bring all the elements together and rename the file, whilst also trimming the 's' from 'houses'.    
    Rename-Item $f.FullName "$($propHouses[0])$($splitOnDashes[1])$($propHouses[1].TrimEnd('s'))$($splitOnDashes[2]).$($propHouses[1].TrimEnd('s'))" -Force
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Yet another way is to use `switch` to loop over the lines in each file and update the lines that match a certain regex pattern:

```
$propertyFiles = Get-ChildItem . '*.property' -File -Recurse
foreach ($file in $propertyFiles) {
    $newContent = switch -Regex -File $file.FullName {
        # update strings that match this pattern
        '(Prop)\.?(house).*(\d{4})-?(\d+)$' { 
            '{0}{1}{2}{3:D2}.{2}' -f $Matches[1], $Matches[3], $Matches[2], [int]$Matches[4]
        }
        default { $_ }  # output unchanged when no match
    }
    $newContent | Set-Content -Path $file.FullName
}
```